# Using reg unload gives access denied error

Tags: powershell

I am trying to load an ntuser.dat and view part of it, after I have viewed what I need I am unable to use reg unload it says "access denied"

I looked and it seems I need to use [gc]::Collect() but that does not work either.

```
reg load HKLM\user C:\Users\user\NTUSER.DAT
$result = Get-ChildItem "hklm:\user\Software"
reg unload HKLM\user
```

If I choose not to do Get-ChildItem the registry unloads fine.

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a handler using the Get-ChildItem and not cleaning it.

Add `$result.Handle.Close()` before unloading, this will close the handle created before.
Also you can add `[gc]::Collect()` for cleaning the handle before unloading the reg hive cleanly.

Answer (score 1):

Just calling `[gc]::collect()` wasn't sufficient on my side, too. But a simple `Start-Sleep` afterwards did the trick:

```
reg load HKLM\user C:\Users\user\NTUSER.DAT
$result = Get-ChildItem "hklm:\user\Software"

[gc]::collect()
Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
reg unload HKLM\user
```